# Cocos2D-iphone trouble using drawAtpoint function within CCTexture2D

Tags: objective-c, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

I'm a cocos2d-iphone newbie and any help would be much appreciated. My problem is I'm trying to use the drawAtPoint method within CCTexture2D but seem to be having no luck. When I run the code I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS runtime error when the program hits the line glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4) within the drawAtpoint function.

Below is the class im using to test the function. It extends CCSprite and I am overriding the draw method with the code below. I'm running cocos2d version 1.0.0 rc2.

```
#import "Background.h"

@implementation Background

-(void)draw
{

    glEnableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState( GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY );

    glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glColor4ub( 255, 255, 255, 255);

    [texture_ drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];

    glColor4ub( 255, 255, 255, 255);

   glDisable( GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
    glDisableClientState( GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY ); 
    [super draw];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

That indicates that your variable `texture_` is not set, or no longer valid.

Where do you set that variable, did you verify that it is properly initiated?

Comment: thanks nash! im using  `background = [[Background alloc] initWithFile:@"woodTile.png"];` i will take a look and see if the texture is verified

Comment: I got it licked now, turns out I needed to add the line `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, [texture_ name]);` to the draw function. Many thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: CCTexture2D -drawAtPoint: calls glBindTexture, don't need to call it from the draw function.